# How can i loops throught all column in each row using pandas in python

Tags: python, pandas

Hello there to all you guy I got a dataframe like this

```
empoyees = [('Jack', 34, 'Sydney') ,
       ('Luke', 31, 'London') ,
       ('Lisa', 16, 'New York') ,
       ('Jimmy', 32,'Tokyo') 
        ]
empDfObj = pd.DataFrame(empoyees, columns=['Name', 'Age', 'City'])
```

how I can loop through columns in each row and get the result like this using pandas in python. The result will be a list like this

```
[(Jack,age,34),(Jack,City,Sydney),(Luke,age,31),(Luke,City,London),(Lisa,age,16),(Lisa,City,New York),(Jimmy,age,32),(Jimmy,City,Tokyo)]
```

or separate list like this

```
[(Jack,age,34),(Jack,City,Sydney)]
[(Luke,age,31),(Luke,City,London)]
[(Lisa,age,16),(Lisa,City,New York)]
[(Jimmy,age,32),(Jimmy,City,Tokyo)]
```

Comment: [What have you tried so far?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592)

Comment: I tried iterrows but it wont work :(

Comment: Please [edit] your question and post [what you have tried so far](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592), including example input, expected output, the actual output (if any), and the [**full text** of any errors or tracebacks](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/359146).

Answer (score 0):

```
# Imports
import pandas as pd

employees = [('Jack', 34, 'Sydney'), ('Luke', 31, 'London'), 
             ('Lisa', 16, 'New York'), ('Jimmy', 32,'Tokyo')]

empDfObj = pd.DataFrame(employees, columns=['Name', 'Age', 'City'])

first_results, second_results = [], []

for _, row in empDfObj.iterrows():
    # To get the first output desired
    first_results.extend([(row.iloc[0], row.index[1].lower(), row.iloc[1]),
           (row.iloc[0], row.index[2].lower(), row.iloc[2])])

    # To get the second output desired
    second_results.append([(row.iloc[0], row.index[1].lower(), row.iloc[1]),
           (row.iloc[0], row.index[2].lower(), row.iloc[2])])

print(first_results)
print(second_results)
```

Outputs

```
[('Jack', 'age', 34), ('Jack', 'city', 'Sydney'), ('Luke', 'age', 31),('Luke', 'city', 'London'), ('Lisa', 'age', 16), ('Lisa', 'city', 'New York'), ('Jimmy', 'age', 32), ('Jimmy', 'city', 'Tokyo')]

[[('Jack', 'age', 34), ('Jack', 'city', 'Sydney')], [('Luke', 'age', 31), ('Luke', 'city', 'London')], [('Lisa', 'age', 16), ('Lisa', 'city', 'New York')], [('Jimmy', 'age', 32), ('Jimmy', 'city', 'Tokyo')]]
```

Let me know if it's ok for you!